# Possibility of Domino Effect

Tags: earthquakes, volcanology

Is there any likelihood that an earthquake could trigger a volcanic event?  I'm thinking that because the Pacific tectonic plate nearly coincides with the "ring-of-fire," particularly along the west coast of the US, that there could a causal relationship between the two events.

Comment: https://www.google.ca/search?q=earthquake+trigger+volcano

Comment: It's more the opposite: volcanoes cause earthquakes.